# error in junit testing

Tags: android, junit

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Class com.android.deviceintelligence.test.Testshutdown has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

thanks for the help in advance.I am fully stuck with this error so please help me.

Comment: The first line says `Testshutdown has no public constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()`. Please check it. And please provide your entire crash log, your code and a detail description of your problem, without which, nobody can help you much.

Comment: I posted one more question with my code so please do solve it.

Comment: Where's the link to your question mate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add one another constructor:

```
public Testshutdown() {
        super("", YourActivity.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Testshutdown extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
you  have to setup a public default Construtor and call within super(Testshutdown.class).